# Saving RGB of a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, type-conversion

I am currently extracting the RGB values from a bitmap. On the internet, the samples all look quite similar:

```
int colour = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

int red = Color.red(colour);
int blue = Color.blue(colour);
int green = Color.green(colour);
int alpha = Color.alpha(colour);
```

There is one thing though that I won't understand: Everybody is using `int` to save the values. I am thinking about using `short` instead to save memory. Is there any good reason not to use `short` that I am missing here? Is it not worth casting the value to `short`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any good reason not to use short that I am missing here?

In most cases `int`'s, four channels per `int`, are better.

> Is it not worth casting the value to short?

It is not worth.

**TL;NR**

It depends a lot on what you do with the values:

1. If you stash them in a `short[]`, this will be more memory efficient than stashing them in a `int[]`, assuming you use one `int` per channel color value. Also, consider what JeppeSRC said: you can use just `byte[]` and, when you use the value, you convert back to `int` with zero-extension like this:

   `int channelColorValue = (int) myBytes[i] & 0xff;`

   This will prevent using erroneous negative values.
2. If you use only a couple of local variables, it does not even matter, but keep in mind that Java, at the bytecode level, performs operations only on 32 or 64 integers, see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1). In this case there is no memory gain using `short` instead of `int`, both will take 32 bits.
3. **The most memory efficient solution** is actually to keep all values in a `int[]`, 4 channels per int (alpha, red, green, blue). You can unpack the `int` and select a single channel color value using bit manipulation, which is exactly what the methods you use do. Example: `int alpha = color >>> 24;`

Answer (score 1):

You are extracting the four channel from a integer which means that every channel is 8 bits, assuming it's a 32 bit integer. So you would be just fine with bytes.

You won't be getting any benefits from using integers or shorts, unless you just save the entire pixel as an integer. If you would use a short then you would lose precision.

Comment: bytes would not be enough, as the values range from 0 to 255 as far as i know, and byte goes from -127 to 127 i think

Comment: Depens if it is unsigned or not.